# Module not found: 'draft-js-export-html'

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm working on a new project with draft.js and have been needing to export raw HTML from my editor. I want to be able to render in another component the HTML as the user is typing.

I did find a nice module to do it, but my app seems not to be able to import the

```
Error in ./src/App.js Module not found: 'draft-js-export-html' in C:\Use
```

It seems to be installed correctly:

```
$ npm draft-js-export-html -v
3.10.10
```

and I'm importing it to my project:

```
import {stateToHTML} from 'draft-js-export-html';
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say for sure. Is it installed in the right directory? This is a stretch, but if you're building it with some kind of "watch" command, you may have to restart it (typically they ignore changes to node_modules)

Comment: `npm draft-js-export-html -v` will not print the version of the installed package but the installed version of `npm` itself. `draft-js-export-html` has no such version.

Comment: @BrianThompson I actually killed Node completely and restarted my dev server. didn't fix it. I installed it at the same place as my other NPM modules

Comment: @trixn that seems to be a good insight.. any way to check if the install was successful?

Comment: `npm list draft-js-export-html` should list the installed version. Good catch @trixn I read right over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm draft-js-export-html -v
```

will not print the version of the installed package but the installed version of `npm` itself.

`draft-js-export-html` has no such version as `3.10.10`. The latest version is `1.4.1`.

Try

```
npm install -s draft-js-export-html
```

If it is already installed this will have no effect.